# When to end support for a browser?

Tags: browser, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I know, this is a very basic and theoretic question, but at which point can browser support be stopped?
I'm still supporting IE8. IE8 has a usage of 0.84 % worldwide.
When should I stop supporting this dinosaur?
When it's below 0.1 % ?

I'm curios, what you guys think!

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should do is look at the browser usage statistics on your own website, so you can get an idea of what the people visiting your site are using.